# How to include colorwheel in online text editor to edit css file

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I want to include a colorwheel in the online text editor in the events onchange or onkeyup/onkeydown when one moves to a particular work like "**color**" It will display colorwheel to select color and to pass the value.
Please let me know If there is anything like this available or please give me suggestions on how to do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plugin that does that:
[Farbtastic Color Picker](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/)

Comment: I have alredy used it, but the thing is to include it in the text editor with on change events.

Comment: @ParveenArora - understood.  Now you just need to bind it to the event you want.  There's a variety of ways to do that, so can you be SPECIFIC on what you want it to do?  You want someone to write you a script that detects that the word you are near is color, and it pops up the colorwheel? As an interface, that could be become complicated quickly.... What would be better is if they clicked a button/link to trigger the color wheel, which then inserted the color where the cursor is.